# Convert from String to Unsigned Long and back

Tags: c++

How do you convert a string to an unsigned long so that the unsigned long represents the characters in the string as 8bit numbers?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: What I want to do is turn a string of 4 characters into a long of the same four characters in ASCII code format.

Comment: Characters _are_ 8-bit numbers (usually). Can you rephrase what you want?

Comment: You've already asked this question (essentially). [edit: I think I got the dups backwards; oh well]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a four character string to a long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370894/converting-a-four-character-string-to-a-long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

largely the same solution, making less assumptions on integral types sizes and checking the maximum string size that can be translated this way:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main()
{
  const size_t MAX = sizeof(unsigned long);

  std::string s("abcd");
  unsigned long res = 0;

  for (size_t i=0; i < std::min(MAX, s.size()); ++i)
  {
    res <<= CHAR_BIT;
    res += (unsigned char) s[i];
  }

  std::cout << std::hex << res;
}
```

prints

```
61626364
```

the casting to `unsigned char` is for the case your string contains high ASCII, i.e. values higher than 127, in which case `char` would be negative. Try the string `"\226\226\226\226"` instead and you will get incorrect result)

**EDIT**: BTW, in your subject you say "and back", so here's the reverse transformation:

```
#include <limits>

std::string tostr(unsigned long x)
{
  // this will mask out the lower "byte" of the number
  const unsigned long mask = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max();

  if (x == 0)
    return std::string("0");

  std::string res;
  for (; x > 0; x >>= CHAR_BIT) {
    res += (char) (x & mask);
  }

  // we extracted the bytes from right to left, so need to reverse the result
  std::reverse(res.begin(), res.end());
  return res;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Cw7hF

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You convert res to hexadecimal format before displaying it. What format is res in originally?

Comment: Could you please explain "std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()"? Presumably it is "1111000000000000" as implied by "res += (char) (x & mask)"?

Comment: @Jona: `res` is binary (as any integer). the `cout << hex << res;` does not change the internal representation of res, it tells `cout` to output it in hex (the default is decimal)

Comment: @Jona: this means "the maximal value that `unsigned char` can hold", which is a fancy way to say `0xFF` :) we need to mask the lower byte of x. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "str" is the string (std::string) and "res" the unsigned long you want to write into.
Like this:

```
for (std::string::iterator i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); ++i) {
    res <<= 8;
    res += *i;
}
```

But it will only work for a string no longer than 4 characters (assuming the unsigned long is 32 bit wide, 8 characters if it is 64 bit)

It will put the first character into the most significant byte of the unsigned long, if you want it the other way around, you could use rbegin, rend.

**Edit:** `res` has to be assigned to itself otherwise the result is lost.

Comment: @balki how do you assign res to itself?

Comment: Also, doesn't the last line _add_ *i (i.e. the byte we're working on) to res whereas we only want to make the first 8 bits of res equal to *i?