# Converting a four character string to a long

Tags: c++, long-integer

I want to convert a four character string (i.e. four characters) into a long (i.e. convert them to ASCII codes and then put them into the long).

As I understand it, this is done by writing the first character to the first byte of the long, the second to the adjacent memory location, and so on. But I don't know how to do this in C++.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the string something like "1234", and you want the value `1234`, or is it "fgu^%", and you just want the character codes interpreted as bytes in a long?

Comment: If you want to parse a string as a long value, use `strtol`. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's your set of four characters:

```
const unsigned char buf[4] = { 'a', '0', '%', 'Q' };
```

Now we assemble a 32-bit unsigned integer:

```
const uint32_t n = (buf[0]) | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
```

Here I assume that `buf[0]` is the least significant one; if you want to go the other way round, just swap the indices around.

Let's confirm:

```
printf("n = 0x%08X\n", n); // we get n = 0x51253061
                           //               Q % 0 a
```

**Important:** Make sure your original byte buffer is **unsigned**, or otherwise add explicit casts like `(unsigned int)(unsigned char)(buf[i])`; otherwise the shift operations are not well defined.

---

*Word of warning:* I would strongly prefer this algebraic solution over the possibly tempting `const uint32_t n = *(uint32_t*)(buf)`, which is machine-endianness dependent and will make your compiler angry if you're using strict aliasing assumptions!

---

As was helpfully pointed out below, you can try and be even more portable by not making assumptions on the bit size of a byte:

```
const unsigned very long int n = buf[0] |
              (buf[1] << (CHAR_BIT)     |
              (buf[2] << (CHAR_BIT * 2) |
              (buf[3] << (CHAR_BIT * 3)   ;
```

Feel free to write your own generalizations as needed! (Good luck figuring out the appropriate `printf` format string ;-) .)

Comment: Make sure that `CHAR_BIT` is `8`!

Comment: One more time you say `CHAR_BIT` and I'll come and hack your brain ;-)

Comment: Teehee. I'd be content with `assert(CHAR_BIT == 8)` in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your bytes are in the correct order for a long on your machine then use memcpy, something like this -

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    long result;

    std::memcpy(&result, data, 4);
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Note that this will be platform dependent for byte ordering in the long which may or may not be what you need. And the 4 is hard coded as the size in bytes of the long for simplicty. You would NOT hard code 4 in a real program of course. All the compilers I've tried this on optimize out the memcpy when optimization is enabled so it's likely to be efficient too.

EDIT: Go with the shift and add answer someone else posted unless this meets your specific requirements as it's much more portable and safe!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string fourCharCode_toString ( int value )
{
    return std::string( reinterpret_cast<const char*>( &( value ) ), sizeof(int) );
}

int fourCharCode_toInt ( const std::string & value )
{
    return *( reinterpret_cast<const int*>( value.data() ) );
}

int main()
{
    int a = 'DROW';
    std::string str = fourCharCode_toString( a );
    int b = fourCharCode_toInt( str );

    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```