# Char array to long to char array

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting a four character string to a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370894/converting-a-four-character-string-to-a-long)

I want to convert a char array to a long and back again but I'm a bit stuck.

This is a fragment of the code I've got so far:

```
char mychararray[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
unsigned long * mylong = (unsigned long *)&mychararray;
cout << *mylong << endl;
```

Which should take the char array, and represent the first 4 bytes (the length of a long) as a long (I think).

Is this correct? And how would I undo it to get the char array back?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The third line was a typo - *mychararray should have been *mylong

Comment: I don't get you you do cout << *mychararray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're assuming `sizeof(long) == 4`, which can be wrong. (Especially on 64 bit platforms). If that assumption is broken, you're in undefined behavior territory: manipulating `mylong` will read/write beyond `mychararray`'s allocated memory.
2. <strike>Your second line has no effect if you don't use `*mylong` on the third line</strike>

You can get back a `char*` with something like:

```
char *thing = reinterpret_cast<char*>(mylong);
```

(You should be using that type of cast in the first case also, it's more explicit than the C-type cast.)

Comment: the third line was a typo. sizeof(long) returned 4 on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to watch out for is the endianess of the CPU if multiple machines are involved.  You'll end up with the chars reversed if they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should conceptually work. Such casts however make assumptions about the underlying platform. If, you are however using C++, I would suggest that you use a [C++ typecast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/).

`reinterpret_cast` is specifically for your case.